# Microsoft.Solver.Foundation .net standard

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package, ms-solver-foundation

Does anybody know if a .net standard version of the Microsoft.Solver.Foundation is going to be available or if it is going to be open sourced?

We are using it in our backend service and would like to convert the service to .net core and to do it I guess we need to have a .net standard version of the nuget package.

Comment: Here is the link you need? https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Solver.Foundation/

Comment: Don't think that it is a .NET Standard version..

Comment: I get this warning when restoring this nuget package

warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.Solver.Foundation 3.1.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.

Is it still OK to use it?

Comment: I tried it out in a small .net core 3 console application but I get the error: "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version=4.0.2.0,..." so I guess it does not work on .net core.

Comment: So, our solution was to rewrite the part using "Microsoft.Solver.Foundation" to use "Google.OrTools" which is .net standard 2.0.

Comment: If you get hold of the Nuget package (Microsoft.Solver.Foundation) you can decompile it, create a new .NET Standard project, add the code and recompile. Bit of a pain, but you'd only need to do it once.